# PMML document parsing

Tags: java, xsd

I'm using ***jpmml*** library to parse the PMML document(xml document with root element PMML). I'm able to parse some of the elements but not all. Here, I'm not able to parse **CategoricalPredictor** attribute inside the **RegressionTable** element. The code for parsing **CategoricalPredictor** is :

```
    RegressionTable regressionTable = new RegressionTable(intercept);
    List<CategoricalPredictor> categoricalPredictor=regressionTable.getCategoricalPredictors();


    /*Categorical predictors*/

    System.out.println("Categorical Predictors:");
    for(CategoricalPredictor c : categoricalPredictor){

        System.out.println("Name :"+c.getName()+",\tValue :"+c.getValue()+
                ",\tCoefficient :"+c.getCoefficient());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

With this code I'm getting nothing but *Categorical Predictors:* as output.

What should I do to get it? Your effort will be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `RegressionTable#getCategoricalPredictors()` on a newly constructed `RegressionTable` instance. The getter returns an empty `List`, which is the expected behaviour.

If you want to work with an existing `RegressionTable` instance then you need to load it from PMML file something like that:

```
PMML pmml = ...
RegressionModelManager regressionManager = new RegressionModelManager(pmml);
RegressionModel model = regressionManager.getModel();
List<RegressionTable> modelTables = model.getRegressionTables();
for(RegressionTable regressionTable : regressionTables){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it with the help of your answer